# How can I append my pictures to my function and append my parameter to my function as a src

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function which I invoke 3 times, But I would like to know whether it's possible to use an image as an argument.

If the answer is yes, then my next question: How can I append the parameter to my  `<img src>`?

The code:

```
function getAnchorTags(link, image) {
    let anchors = ($('<a/>', {
        'href': link
    })).html('this is where the img etc. should come');
    return anchors;
}

$(function () {
    $(rowEblock().append(getEblock()).appendTo('.panel-footer'));
    $('#anchorAppender').append(getAnchorTags('#'), getAnchorTags('#'), getAnchorTags('#'));
});
```

So what to give you an idea of what I am looking for:

```
<a src="example.com"><img src="aCertainImage"></a>
```

The above code, but in javascript (with the function) and using the parameters.

The code that invokes `getAnchorTags()`:

`$('#anchorAppender').append(getAnchorTags('#'), getAnchorTags('#'), getAnchorTags('#'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `src` and use it inside the `.html()` like :

```
function getAnchorTags(link, image) {
    let anchors = ($('<a/>', {
        'href': link
    })).html('<img src="'+image+'">');

    return anchors;
}

$(function () {
    $(rowEblock().append(getEblock()).appendTo('.panel-footer'));
    $('#anchorAppender').append(getAnchorTags('#','image_src_path'), getAnchorTags('#','image_src_path'), getAnchorTags('#','image_src_path'));
});
```